# LibreOffice/OpenOffice Calc not letting to write phones

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I input phones from keyboard as:

```
+9 (999) 999-99-99
```

After each cell edit the program shows a message that it detected an error in a formula:

> LibreOffice Calc found an error in the formula entered. Do you want to
>   accept the correction proposed below?
>
> =+9 *(999)

It makes me make an additional click on each cell edit. Both LibreOffice and OpenOffice behave exactly the same.
How do I disable this behavior?

Comment: Use a custom (user defined) number format.

Comment: If you add a leading space, it will treat it as text and not prompt you.